# Is there a Google Play Game Services HUB Activity for Apps?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

Is there anything in the Google Play SDK that opens a general Activity for showing **all** services for an app? A sort of "HUB" page for the game?

What I mean is, there are calls like:

```
StartActivityForResult(mGooglePlayClient.AllLeaderboardsIntent, REQUEST_ACHIEVEMENTS);
```

Which will bring up a page off all the leaderboards in a game.

Or this one:

```
StartActivityForResult(mGooglePlayClient.AchievementsIntent, REQUEST_ACHIEVEMENTS);
```

Which brings up a page with all the achievements for the game.

I was hoping that there might be an Activity which shows all of this information on a single page. Like a "Hub" page for my game. Rather than having induvidual buttons for all the different services, I could just have this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Google is adding the feature today, along with a bunch of other Game Services to be closer to PSN/Xbox Live.

http://www.polygon.com/2014/6/25/5839402/google-play-games-quests-saves